# Authenticate sharepoint web service error

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, sharepoint

I am trying to authenticate against the authentication.asmx web service.

In visual studio, I right click on my project and click 'Add Service Reference'.

I enter the following into my address:

```
https://my-domain.com/sp/testsite/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx
```

And click the 'Go' Button. I then get the following error. I can access the webservice via the browser without any issues though, so not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
The document at the url https://my-domain.com/sp/testsite/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'https://my-domain.com/sp/testsite/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'There was an error downloading 'https://my-domain.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx?disco'.'.
  - The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://my-domain.com/sp/testsite/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx'.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://my-domain.com/sp/testsite/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx'.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Comment: Hi there, do you have any luck if you try and add it as a [`Web Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx) instead of as a service reference?

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. Same problem. I have noticed that if I go to authentication.asmx?wsdl I get a blank page, where as if I login through the sharepoint site and then visit it, I get the proper XML WSDL file. Does this mean I need to authenticate in some other method?

Comment: Is the root of your SharePoint instance `https://my-domain.com/sp` and `https://my-domain.com/sp/testsite` is just a site underneath that? If so, does it make any difference if you try and access `https://my-domain.com/sp/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx` (or `https://my-domain.com/_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx` if `https://my-domain.com` is the root of your SharePoint instance)?